# How to get all reviews of a product using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a e-commerce app and now I want to get all the review of a product using nodejs and database is mongoDB (using mongoose). This is my Schemas:

User Schema:

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Product Schema:

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "users",
  },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  image: { type: String, required: true },
  brand: { type: String, required: true },
  category: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  reviews: [
    {
      name: { type: String, required: true },
      rating: { type: Number, required: true },
      comment: { type: String, required: true },
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "users",
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
    },
  ],
  rating: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  reviewNumber: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  price: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
  countInStock: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
});
```

I want to get all reviews of a product. It's my controller

```
//* desc   Get all reviews
//* route  GET /product/:id/review
//* access Public
const getAllReviews = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
    const reviews = product.reviews.find({});
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      reviews,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Internal server error",
    });
  }
};
```

But when I test by using Postman. The result is error 500. How can I get all review?

Error:

```
TypeError: #<Object> is not a function
    at Proxy.find (<anonymous>)
    at getAllReviews (D:\Workspace\Projects\e-commerce\server\src\controllers\product.controller.js:210:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Please provide the error. What did the console.log(error) print? I guess it fails to find the product. but without the error its hard to tell

Comment: I have already updated the error

Comment: Do you want to find all the reviews from one user on that product or all the reviews for that product?

Comment: I want to find all the reviewers for that product from all users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send all the reviews for the product, you **don't need to add this line**

```
const reviews = product.reviews.find({});
```

You can simply type

```
const reviews=product.reviews;
```

Comment: I tried it and success. Thank you. But now I want to get reviews from a user. How can I do that

Comment: @LXT Every user is going to have only one review for a product right?

Comment: nah. A user has many reviews

Comment: `const userReviews = product.reviews.filter(review => review.user.toString() === userId   );`  You can run something like this after finding the product  @LXT

Comment: As you mentioned a user can have many reviews for a single product. `.filter()` will help you with that. If it was only one review per user per product, then you can use `.find()`

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your support